# replace space in text without affecting html tags

Tags: html, objective-c, regex

I need to replace the space inside the html by `&nbsp;`, but without affecting the spaces inside of .

So that something like this: `Hello <font color="red"> How Are <font color="black"> You?`
would become this: `Hello&nbsp;<font color="red">&nbsp;How&nbsp;Are&nbsp;<font color="black">&nbsp;You?`

It changes the spaces outside of the tags, but the spaces inside the tags aren't affected.

---

I have tried this sample code that was suggested by someone:

```
 NSString *string = originalHTMLString;

 NSError *error = nil;
 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?i)(<script(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"]|'[^']*')*>)\s+</script\\s*>|<style(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"]|'[^']*')*>)\s+</style\\s*>|<textarea(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"]|'[^']*')*>)\s+</textarea\\s*>|</?[a-z](?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"]|'[^']*')*>|\\S+)|\\s+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
 NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@" &nbsp;"];

 finalHTMLString = modifiedString;
```

But it didn't work. Just returned Null, I think the RegEx pattern is wrong.

---

This is some sample html I have to convert:

```
  <samp class="s22">من مشاكل جرّأء العثّ والفيروسات منذ سنوات. إلاّ أنّ أمرًا ما حدث في الأعوام الماضية وسبّب المشكلة".</samp></p> <p class="mytext-19" dir="RTL"><samp class="s20">ويعتقد هاكينبرغ أنّ الأمر بدأ منذ عام </samp><samp class="s21">2004</samp><samp class="s22">. ففي أيار ذلك العام، اشتكى مزارعو العنبيّة في ماين من أنّ نحلهم الذي يلقّح محصولهم كان يُنتج طرودًا ويغادر الخلايا. كما أنّ نحل الخلايا الأخرى لا يسرق العسل الموجود في الخليّة المتروكة.</samp></p> <p class="mytext-19" dir="RTL"><samp class="s20">وحين بحث عن تفسير لهذا السلوك الغريب، اكتشف أنّ مزارعي التفاح في واشنطن استعملوا مبيدًا جديدًا يحتوي على النيونيكوتينوييد يُدعى </samp><samp dir="LTR">Assail</samp><samp class="s22"> لأشجارهم. وكان نحله يلقّح تلك الأشجار في الربيع.</samp></p> <p class="mytext-19" dir="RTL"><samp class="s20">ذاك الشتاء (</samp><samp class="s21">2004</samp><samp class="s22">-</samp><samp class="s21">2005</samp><samp class="s22">)، خسر ثلثَ نحله تقريبًا، وهي نسبة أعلى بكثير من المعتاد. وفي العام التالي نفق النصف كما أُبلغ عن خسائر في مختلف أنحاء البلاد.</samp></p> <p class="mytext-19" dir="RTL"><samp class="s20">يقول هاكنبيرغ: "لقد ساءت الأمور جدًّا، ولكنّ أحدًا لم يتمكّن <samp class="s37">من معرفة السبب". لهذا، ففي صيف عام </samp></samp><samp class="s61">2006</samp><samp class="s38"> عقد اجتماعًا مع علماء في نبراسكا ليحاول إيجاد سبب للارتفاع السريع في معدّل نفوق </samp><samp class="s26">النحل. "قيل إنّ الاجتماع ضمّ أذكى العقول ولكنّنا جلسنا ليومين نتباحث من دون التوصّل لشيء". وبعد بضعة أشهر هلك ثلثا ما تبقّى من نحله.</samp></p> <p class="mytext-19" dir="RTL"><samp class="s20">أعطى النحّالون الذين نقلوا </samp><samp class="s21">1</samp><samp class="s22">.</samp><samp class="s21">2</samp><samp class="s22"> مليون قفير إلى بساتين اللوز في كاليفورنيا في شباط أوّل مؤشر على صحة النحل عام </samp><samp class="s21">2008</samp><samp class="s22">. لم تكن الإشارات جيّدة. <a class="MyAppHighlight1" style="background-color:pink; color:black;" name="M10">فمن بين الاثني عشر نحّالاً تقريبًا الذين تحدثنا إليهم</a>، اثنان منهم فقط دخلوا الشتاء سالمين نسبيًّا. أمّا الباقون فخسروا ما يتراوح بين </samp><samp class="s21">30</samp><samp class="s22"> بالمئة و</samp><samp class="s23">60</samp><samp class="s22"> بالمئة من قفرلوا الشتاء سالمين نسبيًّا. أمّا الباقون فخسروا ما يتراوح بين </samp><samp class="s21">30</samp><samp class="s22"> بالمئة و</samp><samp class="s23">60</samp><samp class="s22"> بالمئة من قفر\330انهم بما بدا شبيهًا بداء <samp class="s37">انهيار الخليّة. ومن بين عمليات الهجرة الاثنتي عشرة التي تابعتها وزارة </samp>الزراعة الأميركيّة من أيلول <samp class="s37">العام </samp></samp><samp class="s21">2007</samp><samp class="s22"> وحتّى ربيع <samp class="s37">العام </samp></samp><samp class="s21">2008</samp><samp class="s22">، ظهر في خمس </samp><samp dir="LTR" class="s2"><span style="display:none;">00002</span> </samp><a style="color:transparent;" name="00003"></a><samp><span style="display:none;">00003</span></samp></p> <p class="bigtitle">&nbsp;</p> <p class="bigtitle">&nbsp;</p> <p class="bigtitle-3" dir="RTL"><samp class="s4">عَالَمٌ بِلا نَحْل</samp></p> <p class="bigtitle-3" dir="RTL"><samp dir="LTR" class="s5">A World Without Bees</samp></p> <p class="mo2allef">&nbsp;</p> <p class="mo2allef">&nbsp;</p> <p class="smallertitleCxSpFirst-6" dir="RTL"><samp class="s7">تأليف</samp><samp class="s8">:</samp></p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a RegEx answer, but in Objective-C this should take a string called `originalHTML`, switch out all of the spaces outside of tags, and save it as a string called `finalHTML`

```
NSString *originalHTML = @"Your backslashed HTML Here";
NSString *finalHTML = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
BOOL insideTag = NO;
BOOL convertSpace = NO;

for (int i = 0; i < originalHTML.length; i++) {

    unichar uniCharacter = [originalHTML characterAtIndex:i];
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", uniCharacter] isEqualToString:@"<"]) {
        insideTag = YES;
    }
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", uniCharacter] isEqualToString:@">"]) {
        insideTag = NO;
    }

    if (!insideTag) {
        if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", uniCharacter] isEqualToString:@" "]) {
            convertSpace = YES;
        }
    }

    if (!convertSpace) {
        finalHTML = [finalHTML stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", uniCharacter]];
    } else {
        finalHTML = [finalHTML stringByAppendingFormat:@"&nbsp;"];
        convertSpace = NO;
    }

}

NSLog(@"%@", finalHTML);
```

*Note, this will not work if you just have a less than sign or greater than sign in your html body that is not part of a tag. If you need to write Less Than< or Greater Than> In your actual body text please use `&lt;` or `&gt;`

Comment: Albert, can't thank you enough, truly you saved my day. Thank you very much, and I truly wish you success in your life.

Comment: Albert I'm facing an issue with this function, when I have big html file, its exhausting the memory and breaking out of the application with "Error due to memory"

Comment: @coder do you not have ARC enabled? I wrote this with that in mind haha... We probably want to *cast all of our `[NSString stringWithFormat` and then release them each time we run through the loop.

Comment: Albert thank you very much for your assistance so far, I have been working on this project since 3 years and at the time arc didn't exist I have been searching about this option and it seems if I want to use now I will have to change so many things in my code. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @coder Sure :D You don't need ARC for this code to work you will just have to release memory manually... I'm not the best at doing this haha, by the time I started coding heavy duty processing apps, ARC existed. You should post another question with my code snippet with "memory management" tags. And unfortunately I won't be able to answer that one like I did with this, but someone else on this site surely can! (Probably even today!) Good luck my man!

Comment: @coder Ah! Just a figure of speech :) Good luck woman! Haha :D