# UIWebView clipped for Arabic content on iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, epub3

I am facing a problem with the latest iOS version (10.3) concerning arabic content epub loaded on UIWebView. The text gets clipped on the left side as shown by the screenshot.

[image: text]

The same problem is faced on iBooks as I try to load the file on it.
This problem has arisen previously on iOS 7 but was later fixed in iOS 8.

This question has been already tackled in this link:
[webview clipped on ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778429/webview-clipped-on-ios7)
but the answers are not applicable. Are there any other approaches?

UPDATE:
Kindly note that this is the CSS used for the paging of the epub, and this is how the margin is set, and manipulating the margins and width percentage or the width size, doesn't solve the problem.

```
 html {
     height:840px;
     font-size:24px;
     width:100%;
 }

 body {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     width:100%;
 }

 #viewer {
     width:668px;
     height:840px;
 }

 #book {
     width:668px;
     height:840px;
     margin-left:50px;
     margin-right:50px;

     -webkit-column-count:auto;
     -webkit-column-width:668px;
     -webkit-column-gap:100px;
     text-align:justify;
 }

 .h {
     margin-top:8px;
 }
```

Comment: Does adding a content inset do anything?

Comment: I have updated the question to include what is used for pagination and to manipulate the text margins and width if the view. As mentioned in the update manipulating these input doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Should I use another way to manipulate the width or the margins of the displayed html?

Comment: I was talking about `[[yourWebView scrollView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(...)];`. Probably it's not the issue, but it's worth the try.

Comment: ok will try thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Adding inset to the left does not have solve the problem, thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue, it seems a bug in iOS 10.3 and also still there in 10.3.1, every thing is working fine on any device below iOS 10.3, after a lot of debugging and inspecting elements I found that this problem happens while the Arabic HTML Text alignment was set to justify and text direction is RTL, so I changed the alignment to right and everything works fine -without text justification- I find this bug in any website has RTL direction and justified text.

Here is how to change the direction to the HTML String
Objective-C:

```
NSString *HTMLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body><div style='text-align: right; %@/></body>", yourHTMLString];
[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLString baseURL:nil];
```

Swift:

```
let HTMLString = "<body><div style='text-align: right; \(yourHTMLString)/></body>"
webview.loadHTMLString(HTMLString, baseURL: nil)
```

It is working now with right alignment till we find update in OS web elements.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, I have tried the following based on your suggestion: bodyContents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:right' id='readerDiv' dir='rtl'>%@</div>", bodyContents];

Comment: Can you post your HTML string, it may contain the style='text-align: justify;
and sorry I updated the answer as I forgot to add <body>

Comment: I will check this out, I can make a replace all for the string inside the body. Will try it out and keep me you updated, thank you for the note.

Comment: I tried the following: if([bodyContents containsString:@"justify"])
        {
            bodyContents = [bodyContents stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"justify" withString:@"right"];
        } with no success

Comment: It worked I had to fix the internal .css file in the epub, thank you for your guidance, which I could double up vote, you saved my day, thank you loads

Comment: @coder Glad you found a solution. I took care of that 'double up vote' for you ;-)

Comment: @HeshamHaleem Excellent, Hesham. Thank you!

Comment: @HeshamHaleem could u tell me it is not working for me

Comment: i want to left align in swift inside webview

Comment: did you try: let HTMLString = "<body><div style='text-align: left; \(yourHTMLString)/></body>"
webview.loadHTMLString(HTMLString, baseURL: nil)